# How do I add a darker border color to text?

Tags: text, effects

[image: http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/265/a/2/esdeath_by_im0ren-d804nlf.jpg]

In this image, look at the text. Can you see a dark yellow border of the light yellow text?

Can someone please tell me how to add that?

Comment: Hi spyk3iartist, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you tell us what software you are using? And what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: In my opinion the color of the text is dark yellow, and the light yellow is a sort of glossy effect, similar to the intermediate steps [here](http://www.pxm-tuts.com/tutorials/text-effects/glossy-plastic-text-effect/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect in question is a **glow**. Glow is colour radiating from the object edges, to either inwards or outwards, usually with a blur making the colour a gradient fading away. As in here, this is a white glow with 5 px blur made with Illustrator:

[image: White glow]

Despite the name, glow doesn't have to be an actual glow, but can also radiate darker colours, and at least in Illustrator and Photoshop use any transparency mode. The image above uses Screen transparency mode, which works for lighter colours. This one uses Multiply, to add black glow to the blue, which creates more like inner shadow, or a feathered stroke:

[image: Black glow]

Glow works with any colour edges, so you can use them on strokes as well:

[image: Glow on stroke]

And with text, which is the need in question:

[image: Glow on text]

Glow can either radiate beginning from the image edges towards the center, or from the center towards the edges. They are complementary in a way, so that white glow from center on blue works identically with blue glow from edges on top of white, as this image demonstrates:

[image: Glow from center or edges]

Outer glow naturally can only begin from edges outwards.

This image demonstrates what is needed here. It is yellow text with a brown-red glow colour set on Multiply 40 % and 4 px blur, from edges.

[image: Brown inner glow on yellow text]

Answer (score 1):

**In Photoshop:**

1. Double-Click your text layer to open the *Layer-Style*
2. Apply **Inner Glow** with your desired color

(*Inner Shadow* does pretty much the same)

Hope this helps.